# Gradle not showing whole project tree (i-e Tasks and signingReport)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After upgrading android studio to 4.2 , gradle is not showing files other than just dependencies.
also in terminal it gives this error on (gradle signingReport)

'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[gradle structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKgwk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Gradle
2. Execute GradleTaks (Elephant icon)
3. gradle signingReport (typing and enter)

OR

settings -> Experimetal -> Do not build gradle task list during Gradle sync